# Are there any tools for creating GTFS?

Tags: data, google, general-transit-feed-specification

I was asked to create a feed for a company. Are there any tools I can use or do I have to make the entries one by one,line by line?

What are the tools big agencies use?

Answer (score 1):

Transiteditor ,Transitdatafeeder and several other free and COTS tools are mentiond here https://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/OtherGTFSTools

Comment: Any of them that you personally have used and suggest?

Comment: Sorry,I have never used them by myself.

Answer (score 1):

I've used GTFS editor https://github.com/conveyal/gtfs-editor , and it works pretty well. There is a moderate hump (usage of the command line) to get over for getting it up and running, but once that is done it's straightforward. If that is too much, TransitEditor is hosted and supported.